# How to prove $A$ inverse and $B$ commute

Tags: matrices, analysis

Suppose $A$ and $B$ are nonsingular matrices.
Prove that if $A$ and $B$ commute,then so do $A$ inverse and $B$?

Comment: Why should I do that?

Answer (score 2):

We need only that $A$ is nonsingular:
$$A^{-1}B =A^{-1}BAA^{-1}=A^{-1}ABA^{-1}=BA^{-1}$$

Answer (score 1):

Since $A$ is non-singular, it ensures the existence of $A^{-1}$ and we have by left and right-multiplying by $A^{-1}$

$$AB=BA\iff (A^{-1}A)(BA^{-1})=(A^{-1}B)(AA^{-1})\iff BA^{-1}=A^{-1}B$$

because $AA^{-1}=A^{-1}A=\text{Id}$, which is the identity element of the matrix multiplication.